# Fill rows of columns of a DataFrame with 0s based on the column name

Tags: r, date, dplyr, nested-loops

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like so:

```
dput(head(f))

structure(list(`2021-04-01` = c(18.75, 18.8047425327496, 19.044178996207, 
19.1751973213021, 19.1689792828825, 19.5836158822698), `2021-05-01` = c(18.68, 
18.6054569055353, 18.8313151379181, 19.0204171560939, 19.0789341312536, 
19.5202197400974), `2021-06-01` = c(18.7, 18.6167441350011, 18.8507363020792, 
19.0240964484369, 19.0811699993501, 19.5312231113571), `2021-07-01` = c(18.74, 
18.6232367708829, 18.8951394692142, 19.0857033425782, 19.1976392153446, 
19.6658807214903), `2021-08-01` = c(18.77, 18.644593579267, 18.9246150091022, 
19.1032894987568, 19.2156342675263, 19.6849727955065), `2021-09-01` = c(18.84, 
18.7266061665193, 19.0136981423636, 19.2080462372435, 19.3252661741782, 
19.7976573506291), `2021-10-01` = c(19.16, 19.0429325189963, 
19.2868666432121, 19.5302122400335, 19.6246896164923, 20.0574681959085
), `2021-11-01` = c(19.61, 19.4885636931401, 19.7281581945936, 
19.9833632850547, 20.1125365664892, 20.5253519746824), `2021-12-01` = c(20.49, 
20.3817436029844, 20.615343551369, 20.8552877862877, 20.9919455460469, 
21.3954384388117), `2022-01-01` = c(20.48, 20.3740323095769, 
20.6359913586072, 20.8916278650574, 21.0735209988655, 21.4729020165058
), `2022-02-01` = c(20.61, 20.5005105056777, 20.7692639443274, 
21.0278974843904, 21.2088372694747, 21.6274189250732), `2022-03-01` = c(20.01, 
19.8989327908198, 20.160435596222, 20.4165374436547, 20.5841189948464, 
20.9775903556065), `2022-04-01` = c(17.33, 17.2371485625473, 
17.4547245416883, 17.5005672257715, 17.6708376845902, 18.1363806857805
), `2022-05-01` = c(16.98, 16.8871485729785, 17.1047245517176, 
17.1505672343433, 17.320837688241, 17.7863806850577), `2022-06-01` = c(16.93, 
16.8371485710296, 17.0547245439537, 17.100567227402, 17.270837681622, 
17.7363806838834), `2022-07-01` = c(16.55, 16.4602929774512, 
16.679186983992, 16.72087791148, 16.902375852915, 17.3788582533972
), `2022-08-01` = c(16.55, 16.4602929762459, 16.6791869839035, 
16.7208779112979, 16.902375853404, 17.3788582563241), `2022-09-01` = c(16.63, 
16.5371485669301, 16.7547245454607, 16.8005672316863, 16.9708376873097, 
17.4363806848043), `2022-10-01` = c(17.55, 17.4565144059899, 
17.6932969707138, 17.7610505877454, 17.9658483820753, 18.3789383274342
), `2022-11-01` = c(17.95, 17.8565144105445, 18.0932969766868, 
18.1610505955585, 18.3658483847519, 18.7789383271028), `2022-12-01` = c(18.83, 
18.746506350021, 18.9775786073436, 19.0456532330963, 19.247708755873, 
19.6618961429746), `2023-01-01` = c(18.85, 18.7565144062112, 
18.9932969711003, 19.0610505896545, 19.2658483811053, 19.6789383251607
), `2023-02-01` = c(18.9, 18.8065144004764, 19.0432969669948, 
19.1110505845328, 19.3158483743015, 19.7289383179684), `2023-03-01` = c(18.48, 
18.3965063458801, 18.6275786028996, 18.695653229726, 18.8977087489342, 
19.3118961401579), `2023-04-01` = c(16.45, 16.3946104511309, 
16.6014635966272, 16.5836894226683, 16.7780479423448, 17.1192896129417
), `2023-05-01` = c(16.1, 16.0446104494817, 16.2514635937641, 
16.2336894172376, 16.4280479394591, 16.7692896149847), `2023-06-01` = c(16.05, 
15.9946104513846, 16.2014635962793, 16.1836894234373, 16.3780479477376, 
16.7192896151668), `2023-07-01` = c(15.68, 15.6196427933565, 
15.8264798722289, 15.8067013586247, 15.9929523803558, 16.3360049618321
), `2023-08-01` = c(15.68, 15.6196427956788, 15.8264798738901, 
15.8067013650241, 15.9929523892458, 16.3360049695611), `2023-09-01` = c(15.75, 
15.6946104485846, 15.9014635974283, 15.8836894236607, 16.0780479442838, 
16.4192896139878), `2023-10-01` = c(16.55, 16.4859287021049, 
16.6972792014036, 16.6652734109894, 16.9082634547469, 17.2600362319714
), `2023-11-01` = c(16.95, 16.88772137434, 17.1001895977296, 
17.0660375905701, 17.3119906079332, 17.6598028036498), `2023-12-01` = c(17.83, 
17.7629779733904, 17.9769203281466, 17.9457670813362, 18.1919876279738, 
18.5322466212441), `2024-01-01` = c(17.85, 17.7877213736662, 
18.0001895966288, 17.9660375873591, 18.21199060611, 18.5598028001363
), `2024-02-01` = c(17.9, 17.8377213696917, 18.0501895967882, 
18.0160375825238, 18.2619906037143, 18.609802799337), `2024-03-01` = c(17.48, 
17.412977978269, 17.6269203306822, 17.5957670842671, 17.8419876327419, 
18.182246625778), `2024-04-01` = c(15.58, 15.6320820495314, 15.9040941973079, 
16.0011191104772, 16.1344022617966, 16.2335337117727), `2024-05-01` = c(15.23, 
15.282082046754, 15.5540941922692, 15.6511191067781, 15.7844022615365, 
15.8835337091116), `2024-06-01` = c(15.18, 15.2320820475369, 
15.5040941967701, 15.6011191055654, 15.7344022621257, 15.8335337059841
), `2024-07-01` = c(14.8, 14.8510913081696, 15.1150995970647, 
15.2182582392206, 15.34485846568, 15.4485814541912), `2024-08-01` = c(14.8, 
14.8510913086602, 15.1150995968972, 15.2182582375734, 15.3448584628037, 
15.4485814528923), `2024-09-01` = c(14.88, 14.9320820482739, 
15.2040941957414, 15.3011191040817, 15.434402262001, 15.5335337090296
), `2024-10-01` = c(15.48, 15.4841139854442, 15.5870431340295, 
15.6417314142646, 15.8049227959112, 16.098072929477), `2024-11-01` = c(15.88, 
15.8841139866634, 15.9870431368691, 16.0417314145131, 16.2049227962264, 
16.4980729322541), `2024-12-01` = c(16.75, 16.7489599312631, 
16.8369242831981, 16.8966205174003, 17.071500700515, 17.3712327127006
), `2025-01-01` = c(16.78, 16.6562480763831, 16.6057902890351, 
16.4748384688119, 16.6420566625675, 16.8092903223808), `2025-02-01` = c(16.83, 
16.7062480758168, 16.6557902869362, 16.5248384644428, 16.69205666146, 
16.8592903220325), `2025-03-01` = c(16.4, 16.2779097817421, 16.2307811943544, 
16.1021665690717, 16.2687265649343, 16.4311314730022), `2025-04-01` = c(15.73, 
15.7087537504016, 15.6075842903385, 15.5299411837982, 15.7125519597493, 
15.8306868005935), `2025-05-01` = c(15.38, 15.3587537511295, 
15.257584289102, 15.1799411833166, 15.3625519604448, 15.480686801248
), `2025-06-01` = c(15.33, 15.3087537532081, 15.2075842896311, 
15.129941184956, 15.312551964791, 15.4306868025988), `2025-07-01` = c(14.95, 
14.9219729698033, 14.8130638959243, 14.7435847446705, 14.9181912547184, 
15.0389778390791), `2025-08-01` = c(14.95, 14.9219729696512, 
14.8130638953738, 14.7435847412341, 14.9181912530557, 15.0389778362589
), `2025-09-01` = c(15.03, 15.0087537477099, 14.9075842830852, 
14.8299411740066, 15.0125519532892, 15.1306867930961), `2025-10-01` = c(15.75, 
15.7563564789682, 15.6174493875532, 15.5606783126084, 15.7533723756061, 
15.8531515873088), `2025-11-01` = c(16.15, 16.1563564821382, 
16.0174493913382, 15.9606783194065, 16.1533723777501, 16.2531515879125
), `2025-12-01` = c(17.03, 17.0272458979667, 16.8737455455617, 
16.8203287006477, 17.0225669443998, 17.1255973103374), Date = c("2021-04-01", 
"2021-04-02", "2021-04-03", "2021-04-04", "2021-04-05", "2021-04-06"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see I have a column that is called Date with Dates from `2021-04-01` until `2025-12-31`. I also have columns, one for each month between these Dates. So a column for April 2021, May 2021, ..., December 2025.

What I want is to optimize the `nested for loop` that I am using (maybe with `dplyr`) below:

```
  for(i in  1:nrow(f)):
    for(j in 1:ncol(f)):
      if(as.character(f$Date[i]) != colnames(f)[j]):
        f[i, j] <- 0
```

I tried to do it using the comment's suggestions and it worked, but somehow it is slower:

```
  require(tidyr)
  long <- f %>%
    gather(Month_Product, Price, -c(Date)) %>%
    filter(Month_Product == as.character(floor_date(ymd(Date), unit = "month")))%>%
    spread(Month_Product, Price) %>%
    mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) %>%
    mutate(SPOT = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>%
    dplyr::select(Date, SPOT)
```

So if I were to take only the head of the result `DataFrame` it would look have the column of `2021-04-01` with values since the first 6 Date Values are in the month of `2021-04-01` and the other `columns` values would all be equal to 0.

I hope this is clear I could provide further clarification if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be better to [reshape wide-to-long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/680068), then compare the dates.

Comment: @zx8754 You are a God amongst mere mortels. Thank you sir

Comment: Glad it helped, you are welcome, feel free to submit your final solution below as an answer.

Comment: I will when I am done thanks

Comment: I used the solution in your post but it is weirdly much slower !! do you have any ideas ? or should i just post both codes and ask for someone to help me optimize the original ?

Comment: Yes, please post an example data `dput(head(myData))`: and your current solution below as an answer.

Comment: ok done. thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Base* solution, with the help of *lubridate* package to get the floor date.

```
library(lubridate) # floor_date

# get index where floor date of "Date" doesn't match column name
ix <- matrix(
  rep(head(colnames(f), -1), each = nrow(f)),
  nrow = nrow(f)) != as.character(floor_date(ymd(f$Date), unit = "month"))

# assign 0, based on index, excluding the last "Date" column
f[, -ncol(f)][ ix ] <- 0

# then row sums
data.frame(f$Date,
           SPOT = rowSums(f[, -ncol(f)]))
#         Date     SPOT
# 1 2021-04-01 18.75000
# 2 2021-04-02 18.80474
# 3 2021-04-03 19.04418
# 4 2021-04-04 19.17520
# 5 2021-04-05 19.16898
# 6 2021-04-06 19.58362
```

A bit more clarification: get column names excluding last "Date" column, then repeat each as many as number of rows, then convert to matrix. Then compare this matrix's each column with the floor of "Date" column. This will give us logical (TRUE/FALSE) matrix, which we then use as index to assign zero. And lastly, sum by rows, excluding last "Date" column.

Comment: Thank you I will check if it is optimized and will get back to you